# Code Blocks 13.12 C++ basic for loop debug error

Tags: c++

I am coding in C++ in Code Blocks 13.12 with TDM-GCC compiler version 4.8.1 on Windows 10 64-bit, but while in any other PC I have used (both at school and university wtih Win7 64-bit and Win8 64-bit, respectively) there were no problems with debugging and running programs, in my case I am not even able to compile simple "for" loop. I tried all versions of CB, withou success.
Here is the siplest code, that gives errors:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    for (int i = 0,i < 9,i++)
       cout << "Test, ",i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, it is a sightly modified basic console application in C++.
The errors I get are following:

```
error: expected initializer before '<' token
error: expected ';' before '<' token
error: expected primary-expression before '<' token
error: expected ';' before ')' token
error: invalid operands of types 'int' and '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to binary 'operator<<'
```

I tried everything - form installing different versions of code blocks, to disableing anti-virus software.

Can you tell me what have I been doing wrong?

Comment: Trivial typos. Look up the for loop syntax.

Comment: Just replace the  comma with `<<` here: `cout << "Test, ",i << endl; `

Comment: This has very little to do with CodeBlocks, but all with syntax; use `for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)` and `cout << "Test, " << i << endl;`

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for

Comment: @downvoters. This is a newbie question, but the code is an MVCE by itself, the error message is cited, so why downvote this?

Comment: @decltype_auto There's more required to post good questions here, at least some more research efforts. Questions like this _fix my buggy code please_  crap aren't likely to be useful for anyone researching the site in future, and thus not welcome.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What "research" skills do you expect from an absolute beginner? He simply cannot yet interpret the error messages; that's all. Did you, back when you wrote your second piece of code?

Comment: @decltype_auto IMHO Stack Overflow isn't for such trivia, that's what books or online tutorials are for. But since the popularity of this site has become so big now, its decaying more and more every day.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ There's some inflation of trivial questions. But I don't think it's beginners like the questioner, who at least try to formulate their question properly. The driving force behind the decay you mention, is imho the urban wisdom that it's more profitable to delegate work to other people than doing it yourself. Imho that's why we see trivial questions with the *who'll be champion in completing my assignment?* odor that often.

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop syntax is wrong.

It should be:

`for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)` and also add the `{}` after the `)`.

And also

`cout << "Test, " <<i << endl;` //and also the concatenation was wrong

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The curly braces are not necessary if the loop body contains only one expression.
You should change commas to semicolons between the braces after "for". "for" is not a function, it is a keyword and the statement "int i=0" is not a parameter.

Here is the right code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
       cout << "Test, " << i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```